# How to get File Thumnail android

Tags: android

I want to get file thumnail like APK files or Image files in android , how can I find each thumbnail , I mean image of APK icon or thumbnail of camera images ...

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [LINK](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-get-list-all-installed.html)

```
private ArrayList<String> getInstalledApps(Context context){

    ArrayList<Drawable> results = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
     List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) { 
       results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    }
    return results;   
}
```